# Getting users with permissions for specific devices

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

would like to know is it possible to get users who are allowed to access/login for a specific devices

it's not useful for me to get information for all my servers. i would like to know for some specific devices

please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try the following requests for Virtual Guests:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["vsi1","vsi2"]}]}}}&objectMask=mask[users]
```

**Replace**: $username, $apiKey
and vsi1 and vsi2 with the vsi's hostnames

- In this case the **mask[users]** mask will retrieve a lot of information and it can raise an issue due to the large set of data. See: [How to Solve: Error fetching http headers](https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers), for that reason I recommend to use a mask like this: **mask[users[id,username]]**

---

### To get users which has access for a specific BMS:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectFilter={"hardware":{"hostname":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["server1","server2","server3"]}]}}}&objectMask=users
```

- Unfortunately, in this case it's not possible to get only id and username from users, it will retrieve a lot of set of information from the users

---

### To get users for VSI/BMS through FQDN

I can recommend another alternative using rest, but you can only get devices (bms/vsi) which has a specific text in its **fullyQualifiedDomainName**, in this example I tried for servers with "**testName**", replace it for your requirements

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch?objectMask=mask[resource(SoftLayer_Hardware_Server)[id,datacenter,fullyQualifiedDomainName,users.id,users.username],resource(SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest)[id,datacenter,fullyQualifiedDomainName,users.id,users.username]]

Method: Post

{"parameters":["fullyQualifiedDomainName:testName _objectType:SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest,SoftLayer_Hardware _sort:[fullyQualifiedDomainName:asc]"]}
```

I hope it helps, let me know if you need further assistance or any doubt

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Account::getVirtualGuests](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests)
- [SoftLayer_Account::getHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware)
- [SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch)